# How can I clean up this controller further?

Tags: php, model, controller, laravel

I'm using Laravel for my app, and my registration form routes to the `postRegister()` function in my controller:

```
public function postRegister() {
    $validator = new Services\Validators\User;
    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->firstname = Input::get('firstname');
        $user->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
        $user->email = Input::get('email');
        $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
        $user->birthday = Input::get('birthday');
        $user->save();
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
    return Redirect::to('register')->withInput()->withErrors($validator->getErrors());
}
```

Now, I've managed to move Validation to a service, where the rules and messages are stored, but I'd like to also move the `if ($validator->passes())` block somewhere, and the only place that I can think that would be appropriate to do this is the User model. I can't quite do that, though, because I'm manipulating an instance of that class already.

Is this as clean and efficient as I can get it **as is** or is there another way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent

This is a Laravel package that extends Eloquent. It will pretty much accomplish exactly what you want.

Personally, I don't think there is anything wrong with where you are right now. But Ardent will make your controller even more lean.

Comment: Thanks, I was using Ardent before but that was a while ago, I'll give it another shot. I'm just trying to stick to MVC, where the Controller's job is just to direct traffic. I don't want it to have to insert into the database as well.

Comment: I understand. However, I don't think that having the controller call `save` violates the MVC paradigm. The controller isn't doing the inserting. It is just telling the model that it should persist itself.

Comment: Hmm...true. Okay, I think you have a good point actually. Thanks for the help :) I'll accept your answer asap.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at [Mass Assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment) in the Laravel docs.  Then you could have

**Warning:** untested code...

```
public function postRegister() {
    $validator = new Services\Validators\User;
    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $user = new User(array (
          'firstname'=>Input::get('firstname'),
          'lastname'=>Input::get('lastname'),
          'email'=>Input::get('email'),
          'birthday'=>Input::get('birthday'),
          'password'=>Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
        ));
        $user->save();
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
    return Redirect::to('register')->withInput()->withErrors($validator->getErrors());
}
```

Extra bonus tip - we can use a [mutator](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) on the password.  Then nobody outside of the User model needs to know how we go about hashing passwords.

Once we set up the `setPasswordAttribute` function in the User model ...

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
    }

}
```

... we can set the password by calling `$user->password = Input::get('password');` and the value will be hashed before it's saved to the model.